# Automatic removal of entries in WeakHashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, garbage-collection, weak-references, weakhashmap

There is a WeakHashMap instance initialized with, for example, 500 entries. Now, its keys have not been referenced anywhere in the running application for a day or so. Will this map's entries be removed automatically after a certain time gets passed?

My understanding is that if key is not referenced then corresponding entries will be removed from the map.

Answer (score 3):

It will be removed when GC runs if your key is not referenced anywhere: ([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html))

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface, with weak keys.
>   **An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key
>   is no longer in ordinary use**. More precisely, the presence of a
>   mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded
>   by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and
>   then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively
>   removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from
>   other Map implementations.

The removal time is unknown:

> Each key object in a WeakHashMap is stored indirectly as the referent
>   of a weak reference. Therefore a key will automatically be removed
>   only after the weak references to it, both inside and outside of the
>   map, have been cleared by the garbage collector.

But be careful, some object like boxed Integer of small integers like -127-> 127 are cached by JVM so if you use autoboxed Integer key, it will never be removed from the Map.

Comment: How does GC decide because key is still being referenced from map instance?

Comment: It's up to GC to decide when to remove the object

Answer (score 3):

Well, first we narrow down the question.

**QUESTION:** We have a `WeakHashMap` in which we have some entries. Will those entries will be garbage collected if the entries are not being used?

### Ref code:

```
WeakHashMap<Object, Object> wkMap = new WeakHashMap<>()
Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = new Object();

Objcet obj1Meta = new Object();
Objcet obj2Meta = new Object();

wkMap.put(obj1, obj1Meta);
wkMap.put(obj2, obj2Meta);
```

First of all, it's not about being *used*, neither it has any relation with time: it's about whether the reference to the map (`wkMap` in this case) is *in scope*; if not, then the **entire map is eligible for garbage collection**, that's quite straightforward. But if not, then...

One thing we need to check is whether the objects which are weakly referenced by the keys  of the map are already garbage collected or not. In this case `obj1` and `obj2`.

If these objects have not been garbage collected, then their corresponding entries will be there in the map. **Garbage collector is not going to reclaim**. Again straightforward.

Now the tricky case: the objects referenced weakly by `obj1`, `obj2` have been garbage collected. There is no need of their metadata present in the map `wkMap`. Ideally they should be garbage collected, and eventually they are. But the question is how...

### Step by Step

1. The objects referenced weakly by `obj1`, `obj2` become eligible for garbage collection
2. The garbage collector collects the objects; at this point, the garbage collector checks whether there are any weak references to the object it's collecting. In our case we have two: keys of two entries in the weak hash map `wkMap`.
3. If GC finds some weak references to the object it's collecting, it then checks whether those references have any `ReferenceQueue` attached to it. If there is any then GC puts the weak reference to that `ReferenceQueue`. GC is done.
4. Until now, the entries are there in the map and they are not eligible for garbage collection. And it will be there in the map until someone manually makes the keys set to `null`. Wait, then who does that? Let's see next:
5. That manual clean-up is done by `WeakHashMap` itself. Let us check the `size()` code inside `WeakHashMap`:

   ```
   public int size() {
       if (size == 0)
           return 0;
       expungeStaleEntries();
       return size;
   }
   ```

   Concentrate on `expungeStaleEntries()`; it is the one which removes all the entries from the map which are there in the `ReferenceQueue` as well, and the entries become eligible for garbage collection (a single reference queue is attached to all the weak references used as a key in the map). Check `expungeStaleEntries()` code as well.

Now in a nutshell, **if from your code you call some method on the `WeakHashMap`, which internally calls this `expungeStaleEntries()` method, only then will the entries become eligible for garbage collection**.

### List of methods which call `expungeStaleEntries()`

- `size()`
- `reSize()`
- `isEmpty()`
- `putAll()`
- etc...

Hope this makes things clear.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this map's entries be removed automatically after a certain time gets passed?

It depends on when the Garbage Collector comes. There is no guarantee that it reclaims "garbage" even once a day.

> The behavior of the `WeakHashMap` class **depends in part upon the actions of the garbage collector**, so several familiar (though not required) `Map` invariants do not hold for this class.  **Because the garbage collector may discard keys at any time**, a `WeakHashMap` may behave as though an unknown thread is silently removing entries.
>
> <sup>[JDK 10 - `WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)</sup>

Comment: Does it mean that When next GC cycle runs, GC will decide based on algorithm to remove entries and finally remove if decision is positive

Comment: @AnshulSinghal, right, at some point in time, GC iterates over weakly reachable objects and clears them

Comment: @AnshulSinghal, the result of these GC iterations is reflected into a `ReferenceQueue` which is held by a `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: @AnshulSinghal later, the `ReferenceQueue` will help to decide which entries should be removed. Note that GC does not interact with a `WeakHashMap` in any way.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. This details are quite informative.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
 WeakHashMap<Group,String> map = new WeakHashMap<>();

   Group group1 = new Group();
   Group group2 = new Group();

   map.put(group1,"one");
   map.put(group2,"two");

   System.out.println(map);

   group1 = null;

   System.gc();

   System.out.println(map);
```

In the first print statement , you will see that hashmap has two elements and in the second print statement it will have only one element. Because the reference to the first element is now null. So yes all keys whose references point to null will get removed the next time GC runs.

```
{Group@53e25b76=one, Group@73a8dfcc=two}//First print
{Group@73a8dfcc=two}//Second print
```